# C++ How to make it possible to read and store 100 char 2D arrays [ 500 ] [ 500 ] in ordered manner?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I have a programming homework which requires storing up to 100 char 2D arrays of size up to 500 * 500, together with 4 numbers associated with each of the array. It should be something like that:

```
struct BLOCK {
    short x1;
    short y1;
    short x2;
    short y2;
    char points [ 500 ] [ 500 ]; 
    };
```

The program must read an imput like that:

```
p
identifier_1 x1 y1 x2 y2
...
identifier_p x1 y1 x2 y2
```

where

- p - how many BLOCKs will be declared (range 1 - 100)
- identifier - identifier of BLOCK (range 1 - 10 000)
- x1 y1 x2 y2 - unimportant in this context. Point is that the 2D array that they describe can be up to 500 * 500.

My attempt to make it work fails, when I try to enter p > 9 :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct BLOCK {
    short x1;
    short y1;
    short x2;
    short y2;
    char points [ 500 ] [ 500 ]; 
    };

int main () {

    short numberOfBlocks;

    cin >> numberOfBlocks;

    short indices [ numberOfBlocks ];

    BLOCK BLOCKsTable [ numberOfBlocks ];

}
```

I also noticed, that this thing doesn't work:

```
char array [ 100 ] [ 500 ] [ 500 ];
```

I CAN ONLY USE:

- iostream
- string

I CANNOT USE

- malloc, calloc, alloc etc.
- std::vector

My question:

- How to make this thing work? How to be able to declare up to 100 structs BLOCK?
- Are there other simple ways to achive this goal of declaring and storing 100 2d arrays 500*500?

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Look up `std::vector`.   It is a container in the C++ standard library that manages a resizable array.

Comment: ough... we cannot use this as well

Comment: What kind of requirement is you can't use malloc either? Can you use things that use malloc internally?

Comment: If you can't use `std::vector`, your question is either over-constrained or trying to get you to use non-standard C++ (e.g. compiler-specific extensions).   All you can do - within standard C++ - is create a fixed size array of 100 elements, and simply keep track of the number (100 or less) you are actually using.   It is also not possible to use a variable length array in standard C++ (an array with size determined by the value of a variable) - that is from C, not C++.

Comment: I use g++. Automatic tester on my University uses it as well. It's hard to explain what we can use - this is a beginner course in Programming, 3rd month, so I don't know much about C++ yet.

Comment: What if you use `BLOCK BLOCKsTable[100];` ? That should be approx. 25 MB of memory, so in general it should be possible to allocate such array (even on the stack). Things like `cin >> numberOfBlocks; BLOCK BLOCKsTable [ numberOfBlocks ];` might not work if numberOfBlocks is only known at the runtime (at least it is not supported by the C++ standard, although AFAIK g++ might support that because of compiler extension).

Comment: E.Maskovsky - I tried, it doesn't work. It is basically the same thing as char array [ 100 ] [ 500 ] [ 500 ]

Comment: `cin >> numberOfBlocks; short indices [ numberOfBlocks ];` Would not work because you can only initialize the size of n array on the stack on compile time, so if you'd want to do that kind of thing you'd have to dynamically allocate space for the stack. If you cannot use `new BLOCK[numberOfBlocks]` then your assignment is impossible. good luck!

Comment: Actually, it seems to work for g++ because of compiler extension (and it still seems to do a stack allocation), I just tried. But yes, in general it is not supported by the C++ standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

500 * 500 = 250000. In round numbers, each instance of `BLOCK` is going to take up about 250kb.

Your sample code uses a gcc extension to instantiate an array of up to `n` instances of `BLOCK` on the stack. Ten instances would therefore take up about 2.5 megabytes. I wouldn't expect that to be a problem, but perhaps your lab's Linux machines are configured with a small maximum on the size of each process's stack. In any case, 100 instances of `BLOCK` would be expected to take up 20.5 megabytes on the stack, which is far more likely to use up each process's stack allotment, so this wouldn't work in any case.

The answer to the question "How to be able to declare up to 100 structs BLOCK?" is to simply declare them in the global static namespace, instead of on a stack. Your assignment's conditions are very cagey, they appear to be intended to force you to understand the differences between the various types of instantiated objects -- heap, stack, and static/global.

Comment: I would never thought of that myself, it's such a relief to know why my solution was faulty.

Comment: I've just tried that and in my environment that crashes as well when allocated on stack. So yes, allocate outside of main. The default stack size for g++ (can be changed) apparently depends on the system settings and seems to be pretty low by default. You can check with the "ulimit -s" command which is printing 2046 on my system (that is approx. 2 MB).

Answer (score -1):

You need to dynamically allocate the array of BLOCKs and the dynamically create each block and feed into the array with the identifier/fields (the purpose and nature -int, string, other- of the identifier is not stated in your question)

As pointed out in the comments numblocks is unknown at compile time and therefore bound to fail (the amount of memory on the stack is also limited even if the compiler decides to grant you and exception and do the allocation behind the scenes once the value is known at run-time)

```
int numblocks;
std::cin >> numblocks;

BLOCKS *blarray = new BLOCKS[numblocks];

for(int i=0; i < numblocks; i++) {
   BLOCK *b = new BLOCK()

   std::string identifier;
   std::cin >> identifier;

   std::cin >> b->x1 >> b->y1 >> b->x2 >> b->y2;
   blarray[i] = b;
}
```

Of course you do need to later manage the deallocation of memory with delete and delete []

Note: As why you can't use std::vector if you can use namespace std ... ??? (this was referring to the original question which has been edited to reflect vector cannot be used and removed the reference to being able to use "namespace std")

Comment: The question clearly stated that he cannot dynamically allocate memory. Wrong answer.

Comment: Maybe I cannot read but the OP says specifically he cannot use "malloc, calloc" and does not mention that he cannot use "new/delete" and does not mention he cannot dynamically allocate. It may also be you read something I didn't.

Comment: Did you see "etc" in there?

Comment: Yes, and this restriction seems clearly oriented to the c library forcing the OP to use standard C++ memory management driving him away from old memory management.

Comment: No, this restriction is clearly aimed (together with the reference to std::vector) to prohibit heap allocation.

Comment: That's your opinion and not mine, but no reason to downvote an answer which given the obscurity of the constraints is as valid as yours to declare a fixed size array on the global space.